# How to mount some folders on a different partition

Tags: mount, partition, fstab, ssd

I recently got an SSD for my computer. Therefore I reinstalled my system and mounted `/` on `/dev/sda1` (which is a partition on the SSD).

To protect the SSD, I managed to mount `/tmp` on the RAMdisk. However, I would also want some other folders to be outsourced, not on the SSD *but on my RAID1*.

The following folders should be outsourced:

- `/var/log`
- `/var/cache`
- `/var/games`
- `/var/tmp`
- (do you have any other suggestions?)

I tried to simply mount those folders on a RAID-partition, just like I did with `/tmp` (find a part of my `/etc/fstab` below). Now I know, this was not the right way, instead I would have to use `bind`.

I would need your help for the following issues:

- What preparations are necessary on the RAID (what about permissions, especially)?
- What are the propper mount options in `/etc/fstab`?
- Now that I have done it the wrong way, how would I migrate the data to the correct place (and is this even necessary for those folders?)

a *wrong* part of my `/etc/fstab`
`<raid uuid>` is the same for all of these lines

```
UUID=<raid uuid> /var/log ext4 noexec,nodev,nosuid 0 0
UUID=<raid uuid> /var/cache ext4 noexec,nodev,nosuid 0 0
UUID=<raid uuid> /var/games ext4 noexec,nodev,nosuid 0 0
UUID=<raid uuid> /var/tmp ext4 noexec,nodev,nosuid 0 0
```

Comment: Are those `UUID=<raid uuid>` the same or 4 different ones?

Comment: Have you considered mounting `/var` instead of 4 individual partitions?  And why not use standard `defaults` options when mounting?

Comment: I just wanted to outsource folders with frequent write operations - the choice of those four folders traces back to a german page (http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/SSD/Auslagerung#Unterverzeichnisse-von-var). I also copied settings from there... however, I don't know if this is a good choice - I'm very open for arguments!

Comment: @JohnSiu the same - one of the reason why it's wrong!

Comment: Why 2 `cache`? Is it a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Mount the raid partition to `/mnt/var`

   ```
   UUID=<raid uuid> /mnt/var ext4 defaults 0 0
   ```

   Create mount point `/mnt/var`

   ```
   cd /mnt; mkdir var
   ```
2. Reboot
3. Copy content into `/mnt/var`

   ```
   cp -a /var/log /mnt/var
   cp -a /var/cache /mnt/var
   cp -a /var/games /mnt/var
   cp -a /var/tmp /mnt/var
   ```
4. Modify fstab as follow to mount them to `/var` on next boot

   ```
   UUID=<raid uuid> /mnt/var ext4 defaults 0 0

   /mnt/var/log   /var/log   none bind 0 0
   /mnt/var/cache /var/cache none bind 0 0
   /mnt/var/games /var/games none bind 0 0
   /mnt/var/tmp   /var/tmp   none bind 0 0
   ```
5. Reboot

Comment: thank you! I would rather have all folders in the same partitions (as I then don't have to care about what size each partition needs). Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, that will need to use the bind option. I will update.

Comment: and the options are fine? or should I change them?

Comment: Changes the main one to `defaults`.

Comment: Verify that they are mount as intended, type `mount`.

Comment: thanks! I also want to add that `df -h` is good to verify that everything worked.