# HDD and SDD partitioning

Tags: linux

I have just got my Thinkpad T420 with an additional mSATA drive and i couldn't be more excited.

My current partition layout is:

HDD: /boot 256MB,  /var 30GB, /opt 50GB

SDD: / 15GB, /home/ 50GB, /usr 50GB

Now, my question is: how can i symlink data from the / partition(inside the sdd)to my HDD partitions. I.e. / is mounted, but instead of using the /var, /opt defaults inside of /, i'd be using the HDDs partitions.

Update: Also i can't seem to have /boot on the SSD, because GRUB tends to install on the HDD instead.

I have created 4 different mount points under /mnt, /mnt/usr/, /mnt/var/, /mnt/home, /mnt/opt and changed the mount location via /etc/fstab, so when(hopefully) i reboot, everything is mounted accordingly.

But after a reboot, X isn't displayed, and i have to login manually, which then takes me to the root directory, instead of my /home.

This is a fresh install, so i really don't mind reformatting, but that only takes me back to square one. Any ideas?.

Here's my fstab:
[fstab](http://pastebin.com/pemYMsYS)

Comment: Check this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64098/how-to-mount-some-folders-on-a-different-partition